# Pydev closing parenthesis autocomplete

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Is there a shortcut to jump out of closing parenthesis in PyDev/Eclipse?  Having to hit arrow key to move the cursor outside of the parenthesis is kind of a pain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just type the closing parenthesis and the editor gets me out without adding extra punctuation. Some would argue that this makes the auto placement of parenthesis somewhat redundant, but I find it quite useful

Answer (score 12):

As [Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110451/fabio-zadrozny) said, you can jump out by pressing TAB or Enter, but this option is **turned off by default** and you simply get a few spaces/a new line upon pressing TAB/Enter.

To turn this precious option on, go to:
`Window > Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Typing`
and check "***Enable link on automatic parenthesis or literals closing***".

Answer (score 3):

In the latest PyDev (2.0), it'll now create a link when it auto-closes the parenthesis, so, after it auto-closes you can press either ')', enter or tab to go to the other side (and remember that if you want to go to the next line directly, use shift+enter.

Comment: Hmm... I find that Tab key doesn't work in PyDev the way it does in JavaScript or C/C++ files/perspective, where pressing Tab will place the cursor outside of current quotes/parenthesis. Tested with PyDev 2.5.

Comment: For example in var = {['this', 'is', 'great|']} you have to hit the ' key to get the cursor out of string, ] to get out of array and then } to get out of object. Where while typing this same statement in a JS file, you simply have to hit Tab for each of the cases.

Comment: @Vitaly To get the behavior you want, see Bloke's answer.